# Is the memory address for string literals in different translation units the same?

Tags: c++, memory, string-literals

Suppose we have the following cpp file.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    const char* p1="hello";
    const char* p2="hello";
    std::cout<<p1==p2;
}
```

Output

```
1
```

As we know, p1 and p2 are pointing to the same memory address (correct me if I am wrong).

Now, suppose we have pointers defined in different translation units:

```cpp
//A.cpp
#include <iostream>

const char* pA="hello";

int main(){
    //whatever.
}

//B.cpp
#include <iostream>

const char* pB="hello"; //Same string literal

int whatever(){
    //whatever.
}
```

I would like to know, will the memory addresses pointed by `pA` and `pB` still be the same, and if yes, in which cases they may differ (like using keywords and whatever)?

Comment: "As we know, p1 and p2 are pointing to the same memory address." - We don't know such a thing, it's up to the compiler whether it wants to perform this optimization.

Comment: Your multi-file code won't work, as you have multiple definitions of `main`.

Comment: There is [a case](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zL8Q1zkzBqZPuCxP) in which they differ.

Comment: _"...Whether string literals can overlap and whether successive evaluations of a string-literal yield the same object __is unspecified__. That means that identical string literals may or may not compare equal when compared by pointer...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: @RichardCritten That is even more restrictive (or lenient, depending on the perspective) than I thought. It means that `void f() { for(int i=0; i<10; i++) { const void *p = ""; cout << p; }}` may output 10 different addresses!

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica potentially but in practice ... will have a look for a Standard quote

Comment: @RichardCritten Well, in practice the compiler does not generate any code for the OP's second example at all. ;-)

Comment: [lex.string 9](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#9) _"...Whether all string-literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) and whether successive evaluations of a string-literal yield the same or a different object is unspecified...."_

Comment: @RichardCritten The C++11 standard reads in 2.14.5/8: *"A narrow
string literal has type “array of n const char”[...] and has **static storage duration**."* That would imply to me that subsequent evaluations should yield the same address, but maybe compiler builders wanted more freedom here (imagine a C++ interpreter?). Then, regarding the OP's "as we know", in 2.14.5/12:  *"Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) is implementation defined."*

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica  _"...That would imply to me that subsequent evaluations should yield the same address,..."_ I don't think the __static storage duration__ phrase stops the compiler from allocating 2 distinct objects for 2 identical string in the same translation unit.

Comment: @Richard Well, considering my code (a single string literal): If I'd be forced to decide I'd say it is *one* string literal (the lexical occurrence in the source code) which is, according to the C++11 standard, *one* object with static storage duration (there is no plural in the sentence). Although we are probably trying to find specifications beyond what the standard was trying to specify. (Of course, all bets are off for multiple lexical occurrences of "the same" string, as in the OP's examples -- the standard says that explicitly.) And apparently somebody in the committee objected to that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the [C++ Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) does not enforce whether or not multiply-defined, identical string literals should be merged:

> ##### 5.13.5 String literals        [lex.string]
>
> …
> <sup>16</sup>    Evaluating
> a string-literal results in a string literal object with static
> storage duration, initialized from the given characters as specified
> above. Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored
> in nonoverlapping objects) and whether successive evaluations of a
> string-literal yield the same or a different object is unspecified.

Frequently, compilers (or linkers) offer a command-line switch to decide on whether or not to merge identical strings. For example, the MSVC compiler has the "Enable string pooling" option – `/GF` to merge, or `/GF-` to keep them separate.

Using the following code units:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
extern void other();

int main()
{
    const char* inmain = "hello";
    std::cout << (void*)(inmain) << std::endl;
    other();
    return 0;
}
```

and (in a separate source file):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void other()
{
    const char* inother = "hello";
    std::cout << (void*)(inother) << std::endl;

}
```

Building with the `/GF` switch yields output like the following (the strings have the same addresses):

```
00007FF778952230
00007FF778952230
```

However, using `/GF-` produces:

```
00007FF7D5662238
00007FF7D5662230
```

In fact, even your first code snippet (with minor modifications, shown below), where both literals are in the same translation unit (and even in the same scope) generates two *different* objects when built with the `/GF-` option:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>

int main()
{
    const char* p1 = "hello";
    const char* p2 = "hello";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (p1 == p2) << std::endl;
    // Output: "false" using /GF- or "true" using /GF
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For GCC, I have found vague references that `-fno-merge-constants` is equivalent to the MSVC `/GF-` switch. However, I can't find an authoritative source to confirm this.

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.1.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fmerge-constants)?