# Check if std::vector<const char *> contains character sequence given as const char *

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char, stdvector

When I declare `std::vector<std::string> v`, i can easily check if it contains given char sequence

```
if ( std::find( v.begin(), v.end(), "abc" ) != v.end() )
{
    // some logic if contains
}
```

but if i use `std::vector<const char*> v` and try to apply the same logic to find given char sequence my code does not work properly.

What causes that issue? How can I solve that problem?

**EDIT**

The fastest solution (I care about performance, thats why i said no to `std::string`)

```
bool FindStringInArray( const DynamicArray<const char*>& array, const char* pStr )
{
    return ( std::find_if( array.cbegin(), array.cend(), [&]( const char* p ) 
            { return strcmp( p, pStr ) == 0; } ) != array.cend() ) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Your `std::vector<const char*>` is a vector of *pointers*. Is that what you want, or just a `std::vector<char>` (for a sequence of characters)?

Comment: It works https://godbolt.org/z/5d1vsGEYn

Comment: @MidnightExigent may appear to work, but not guaranteed. related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68484603/4117728

Comment: its not quite clear, what problem you are trying to solve. If you want a vector of strings you can use a `std::vector<std::string>`, `std::string` has an `operator==` that compares the strings

Comment: ha! interesting that `gcc` does that even without optimizations enabled. @Jonathan's answer seems good tho. Although OP should consider `std::string_view` since we're in c++ world

Comment: @MidnightExigent your example only works because you use literals only. See how it fails for sure when you dont https://godbolt.org/z/zdcT654hx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::find` calls `operator==`, which for `const char *` is defined to compare pointer values, not contents. (After all, who says that the pointed-to thing is a string? It could be a single char or even a one-past-the-end pointer to an array.)

You'll have to use `strcmp` with `std::find_if` or iterate over the vector manually.

Answer (score 2):

It is questionable to use a `std::vector<const char*>` to store strings. In your code you compare pointers and thats not going to work.

Note that `std::find` is templated on the type of value to be found and that type is not necessarily the type of the containers elements. Further there is a `operator==` to compare `const char*` with `std::string`. Hence you can use find like this:

```
if ( std::find( v.begin(), v.end(), std::string("abc") ) != v.end() )
{
    // some logic if contains
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to this, c++17 introduced `std::string_view` which is a lite wrapper around `const char*` and overloads the operators correctly. Meant to be the "modern c++" replacement of `const char*`

```
std::vector<std::string_view> v;
if ( std::find( v.begin(), v.end(), "abc" ) != v.end() )
{
    // some logic if contains
}
```